# How to get user's current cellular provider?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to get information about user's current mobile provider(not home carrier)  - for example when he is using roaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so using public APIs at least. It seems too cut off from the rest of iOS to access. That being said, I haven't seen any documentation that confirms it one way or the other. The problem is that I don't know where to look for said information. That's your problem too :). Sorry I can't back it up with any tangible evidence, but it seems too separate based on my gut feeling.